# PF 6000 Atlas Copco Nut Runner code in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to develop a software by using C#.net. that software communicate with Atlas Copco PF 6000 Nut Runner.

I am trying to send the message 00200001000000000000# by using open protocol.

App created tcpclient and socket but this message is working only for PF 4000. I need particular message which is working and acceptable for PF 6000 please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have already solved this issue.

Communication using Open Protocol to any torque controller, PF4000 or PF6000 shall be the same in the communication start sequence. The same message shall work. Do you get any error from the torque controller as an answer?

It also seems that you haven't specified any revision for the communication start, which is needed. Try: 00200001001000000000# for revision 1. I would recommend the highest revision supported by your controller software, can be seen in the appendix provided together with the software.

You also need to make sure to have activated the Open Protocol for the wanted Virtual Station. This is different from the PF4000, due to that PF6000 supports multiple tools per controller unit.